# Can't connect to the MS SQL Server 2008 database instance using Hibernate

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008, java-8

I'm trying to connect to the MSSQL Server using Hibernate. Code I've wrote is ok, when I try to connect to the "normal" database, but I'm always getting exception for one database, which has instance.

Error is:

```
2020-03-06 15:07:01.755  WARN  com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@12fa2433 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
2020-03-06 15:07:01.758  WARN  com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@12fa2433 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@5d00c227
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sk2t6a81cvnu23110fpe1|11389053]-HelperThread-#0
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1e98ae08
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sk2t6a81cvnu23110fpe1|11389053]-HelperThread-#2
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@6c17f8ef
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sk2t6a81cvnu23110fpe1|11389053]-HelperThread-#1
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@6665ca79
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3d2f3d68
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->2sk2t6a81cvnu23110fpe1|11389053]-HelperThread-#0,5,main]
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2336)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2067)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1204)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:825)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

Using the same login password I **can** connect to the database but not programmatically, i.e. using sqlcmd.

How I create connection:

```
    public synchronized static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(Logger log, DbServer dbServer, String dbName) {

        String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s:%d;databaseName=%s", dbServer.getServerName(), dbServer.getPort(), dbName);

        return new Configuration().configure()
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
            .setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "dbo")
            .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect")
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", dbServer.getLogin())
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", dbServer.getPassword())
            .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url)
            .buildSessionFactory();
    }
```

`dbServer.getServerName()` returns "serverName\dbInstance", port is 1433, `dbName` is `master`.
Using Microsoft SQL Management Studio I can connect using the same login/password so I'm pretty sure that it's problem with configuration - I'm using sys admin (sa) so it's not permissions issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was not to use port when I try connect to database. So connection string looks like this:

```
String url = String.format("jdbc:sqlserver://%s;instanceName=%s;databaseName=%s", dbServer.getServerName(), dbServer.getInstanceName(), dbName);
```